# Is there any way to test HAML output in Rails Console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, heroku, haml

I want to do something like this in `console`:

```
= raw CSV.generate_line(array)
```

And see how the output looks like.

The reason being the CSV output on Heroku is adding in extra newlines in every CSV file genrated and I can't replicate this on development. It's not very good practice to try random attempts to fix the problem by deployment =)

If anyone has hints to what might be causing the newline characters, be grateful too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
engine = Haml::Engine.new("%p Haml code!")
engine.render #=> "<p>Haml code!</p>\n"
```

Of course you need to have haml gem required in your app but i assume you have this.

Answer (score 2):

You can also have

```
 include ActionView::Helpers
```

in your console.
and have raw, link_to and other helpers handy.